# How to create a new terminal window from the command line in Red Hat Linux 5.3

Tags: linux, terminal, shell, window

I use [PuTTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY) to get to my [Red Hat Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux) 5.3 workstation from my Windows laptop.

Typically, if I want a new terminal on my Windows 7 workstation from another terminal or mc, I have to type start <ENTER>, and I will see a new terminal window running the default shell.

What is the equivalent command in Red Hat Linux 5.3 (and/or [Solaris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_%28operating_system%29)) to create a new terminal window from the command line? I will be entering this command from the shell prompt or mc's command line.

In Windows, if I want to start another terminal and in that terminal, I want to run a program, I can do "start program.exe arg1 arg2". This will create a new terminal window and runs program.exe in that terminal window. I don't have to create a terminal and then in a separate step run the program. How can I do this in Linux?

Comment: In Windows, if I want to start another terminal and in that terminal, I want to run a program, I can do "start program.exe arg1 arg2". this will create a new terminal window and runs program.exe in that terminal window. How can I do this in Linux ?

Comment: Maybe add this as another question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using PuTTY, I'd just duplicate the session.

Remember that PuTTY is a Windows application, and your Linux machine can't make a new Windows application instance.

If you have an [X Window](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) server (and you can download [XMing XServer](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/) for free), you can run a few different terminals, including `xterm`, `gnome-terminal` or `konsole`, etc.

You can also use the same PuTTY window with multiple sessions with [screen](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/screen/) or [tmux](http://www.linuxcertif.com/man/1/tmux/).

Comment: In Windows, if I want to start another terminal and in that terminal, I want to run a program, I can do "start program.exe arg1 arg2". this will create a new terminal window and runs program.exe in that terminal window. How can I do this in Linux ?

Comment: @anjanbacchu terminal programs take the -e flag for a command

`xterm -e program arg1 arg2` should do it

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're running a X server on your Windows machine, you can't do this and will have to start a new instance of PuTTY. If you *are* for some reason running a X server then you can simply call the terminal emulator name followed by a `&`.

```
gnome-terminal &
```

Answer (score 1):

screen is your friend.

You can have multiple sessions, each running independently.

You can even detach a screen session, log off and shut down your Windows PC completely, go home and start a putty session from home, and re-connect to the detached screen session which will still be running.

Screen is da boss!